# Android 13: determine if a Live Wallpaper is set

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I would to check if my Live Wallpaper App is set as Live Wallpaper.

The following code works on *Android <= 12*, but not in *Android 13 (sdk 33)*.

```
public static boolean isLiveWallpaper(Context context) {
    if (Service._handler == null) {
        return false;
    }
    WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
    WallpaperInfo info = wpm.getWallpaperInfo();
    try {
        return (info != null && info.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

On Android 13 `wpm.getWallpaperInfo()` always return `null`.

Why? I searched on Google and on the Android Developer Documentation, but I did'n find anything...

Edit:
I set the live wallpaper with this code and it works, but I can't check programmatically if the live wallpaper is setted.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT,
        new ComponentName(context, Service.class));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: The docs on that function claims that it returns null for a static image, could this be the situation?

Comment: @PaulT. no, this is not it, I set the live wallpaper (I added a piece of code). And the same code works on previous versions (<= 12).

Comment: Then it sounds like an issue to possibly raise with Android for v13? Your example should be enough information for them to reproduce.

Answer (score 2):

Check the source code of [WallpaperManagerService.java](https://frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/wallpaper/WallpaperManagerService.java)

```
    public WallpaperInfo getWallpaperInfo(int userId) {
    final boolean allow =
            hasPermission(READ_WALLPAPER_INTERNAL) || hasPermission(QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES);
    if (allow) {
        userId = ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(Binder.getCallingPid(),
                Binder.getCallingUid(), userId, false, true, "getWallpaperInfo", null);
        synchronized (mLock) {
            WallpaperData wallpaper = mWallpaperMap.get(userId);
            if (wallpaper != null && wallpaper.connection != null) {
                return wallpaper.connection.mInfo;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

We can see some permissions are needed to query the wallpaper info.

So, please add the following permission request in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` works, but there is a warning: `A <queries> declaration should generally be used instead of QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES; - https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring`
Which is the correct query for the live wallpaper? Or do I have to use `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES'?

Comment: If you are trying to find out if the current live wallpaper component is in a known list of packages, you can provide that entries in the query list. Otherwise, you cannot give a list of names which you don't know yet. But using QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission will require additional Google review when you publishing your app on GooglePlay, just be careful.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/247921423) reported to Google. I'm not sure if Google is going to fix it. This is the workaround I've been using. `LiveWallpaperService.isEngineRunning` can tell your app is set as LiveWallpaper or not.

```
class LiveWallpaperService : WallpaperService() {
    ...
    
    class MyEngine : WallpaperService.Engine() {
        ...

        override fun onCreate(surfaceHolder: SurfaceHolder) {
            if (!isPreview) {
                isEngineRunning = true
            }
        }
    
        override fun onDestroy() {
            if (!isPreview) {
                isEngineRunning = false
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
       var isEngineRunning = false
    }
}
```